# STM32 - Stepper Motor doesn't stop when it is called in HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback()

Tags: c++, embedded, microcontroller, stm32f4

I am using Nucleo-F401RE to control a LED and an X-Nucleo-IHM01A1 that drives a stepper motor.

The MCU receives message rxdata[3] through UART DMA Interrupt. The control of the LED is working correctly. However, the motor is spinning continuously without stopping when MCU receives a message to control the motor.

How can I make the stepper motor work correctly with DMA interrupt?

```
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart){

  /* Prevent unused argument(s) compilation warning */

   UNUSED(huart);

   /* NOTE: This function should not be modified, when the callback is needed,

    the HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback could be implemented in the user file

    */

   ///Copy message

   MessageReceived();

  }




void MessageReceived(){

   if (rxdata[0] == 0x0A) //Led

   {

         HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, rxdata, 3, 500);

         if(rxdata[1] == 1){

         HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET); //Turn on

         } else if(rxdata[1] == 2){

               HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_SET); // Turn off

         }

   } else if (rxdata[0] == 0x0B) // Motor Control

   {

        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, rxdata, 3, 500);

         uint32_t n_steps = rxdata[2];

         if(rxdata[1] == 0x01){ //If receive move forward command

              BSP_MotorControl_Move(0, FORWARD, n_steps);

              BSP_MotorControl_WaitWhileActive(0);

         } else if(rxdata[1] == 0x02){ //If receive move backward command

              BSP_MotorControl_Move(0, BACKWARD, n_steps);

              BSP_MotorControl_WaitWhileActive(0);

         }

   }

  }
```

Comment: I suspect the `MessageReceived()` function is executing within an interrupt context.  Are you sure that `BSP_MotorControl_Move()` and `BSP_MotorControl_WaitWhileActive()` can be called from an interrupt context?  Do the motor control functions work as expected when called from `main()`?  If so, then try redesigning the interrupt handler to set a flag rather than calling the motor control functions.  Then test/check the flag from the main loop, and then call the motor control functions from the main loop when the flag has been set by the interrupt handler.

Comment: There is likely already a flag available in the DMA hardware, the very one used to trigger the interrupt. Ditching the interrupt and polling that flag instead might be the way to go.

Comment: I am new to embedded programming. As the program is not working properly, I think BSP_MotorControl_Move() and BSP_MotorControl_WaitWhileActive() can not be called in the interrupt context, or it has to be handled well. Yes, the motor control functions work well when called from main without depending on the received message. Could you tell me more clearly what kind of interrupt handler I need to use, and what function, and what kind of flag to use? I can see there are DMA IRQHandler and USART IRQHandler.